# R 4.1.2: Dynamically check values for a cumulative pattern. Null following values if that pattern occurs at any time across values

Tags: r, conditional-statements, user-defined-functions

This relates to another problem I posted, but I did not quite ask the right question. If anyone can help with this, it would really be appreciated.

I have a DF with several players' answers to 100 questions in a quiz (example data frame below with 10 questions and 10 players-not the real data, which is not really from a quiz, but the principle is the same).

My goal is to create a function that will check when a player has answered 3 questions incorrectly cumulatively at any point during their answers, and then change their following answers to the string "disc". I would like to be able to change the parameters also, so it could be 4 or 5 questions incorrect etc. In the df: 1=correct, 0=incorrect, and 2=unanswered. Unanswered is considered incorrect, but I do not want to recode it as 0.

```
df=data.frame(playerID=numeric(),
              q1=numeric(),
              q2=numeric(),
              q3=numeric(),
              q4=numeric(),
              q5=numeric(),
              q6=numeric(),
              q7=numeric(),
              q8=numeric(),
              q9=numeric(),
              q10=numeric())

set.seed(1)
for(i in 1:10){
  list_i=c(i,sample(0:2,1),sample(0:2,1),sample(0:2,1),sample(0:2,1),sample(0:2,1),sample(0:2,1),sample(0:2,1),sample(0:2,1),sample(0:2,1),sample(0:2,1))
  df[i,]=list_i
}
```

So, in this DF, for example, playerID=3,8 and 9 should have their answers="disc" from q4 onwards, whereas playerid5 should have “disc” from 8 onwards. So anytime there are 3 consecutive incorrect answers (including values of 2), the following answers should change to “disc”.

I presume the syntax would be a for loop with an if statement inside using mutate or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution using `mutate` and `across`:

```
df %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    # Mutate across all question columns
    across(
      starts_with("q"),
      function(col) {
        # Get previous columns
        col_i <- which(names(cur_data())==cur_column())
        previous_cols <- 2:(col_i-1)
        
        # Get results for previous questions as string (i.e. zero, or 2)
        previous_qs <- select(cur_data(), all_of(previous_cols)) %>%
          mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(.x %in% c(0,2)))) %>%
          tidyr::unite("str", sep = "") %>%
          pull(str)

        # Check for three successive incorrect answers at some previous point
        results <- grepl(pattern = "111", previous_qs)
        
        # For those with three successive incorrect answers at some previous point, overwrite value with 'disc'
        col[results] <- "disc"
        col
      }
    )
  )
```

Comment: Yes that works-thank you. If I wanted to change the check to be for four/five incorrect answers, would I modify results <- grepl(pattern = "111", previous_qs) to "1111" or "11111" etc?

Comment: Yes, thats right.

Comment: Here : col_i <- which(names(cur_data())==cur_column())
        previous_cols <- 2:(col_i-1)

If it's not too much trouble, would you detail what this is doing?

Comment: `cur_data()` and `cur_column()` are [context dependent expressions](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html). Within `across()` - which is iterating across each of the columns - `cur_data()` returns the whole dataframe and `cur_column()` returns the name of the current column. So `col_i` returns the index of the current column within the whole dataframe (i.e. 2 for q2, 3 for q3 etc.), and previous_cols is the index of all previous columns/questions.

Comment: mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(.x %in% c(0,2)))) %>%
          tidyr::unite("str", sep = "") %>%
          pull(str)

Does the first line change(mutate) everything in previous_qs to numeric values? Then what is getting united and pulled in the next two lines? Sorry, I thought a for loop might do it so some of this is going over my head.

Comment: The `mutate` iterates `across` all the columns (i.e. the previous questions) and turns any values of 0 or 2, to 1 (`.x %in% c(0,2)`) turns it to TRUE, then the `as.numeric` turns the TRUE into a 1. Any values of 1 (initially turned to FALSE) are similiarly turned to 0. `tidyr::unite` just pastes the values in columns together, so it takes all the 1s and 0s from previous questions and turns it into a single string of e.g. "11000" (in a new column). `pull` then extracts this column as a vector so you have something the same length as the original column (i.e. 1 value for each row)

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanations; I'll mark as accepted answer.

Comment: Realise this is old now, but, if you do see this, is there anyway the code can be modified to look for a pattern of 4/5 incorrect answers at any point (so for every five answers if there are 4 incorrect, and not necessarily in a row-eg. 00122 or 21000 and then change the rest to disc? So the function would be continuously checking for 4 out of 5 wrong answers at any point, and they don't have to be cumulatively wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

n <- 100
f <- function(v, cap, new_value){
  df <- 
    data.frame(v = v) |> 
    mutate(
      b = cumsum(v),
      v_new = ifelse(b > cap, new_value, v)
      )
  return(df$v_new)
}

# apply function to vector
v <- runif(n)
v_new <- f(v, 5, "disc")

# apply function in a dataframe with mutate 
df <-
  data.frame(a = runif(n))
df |> 
  mutate(
    b = f(a, 5, "disc")
  )
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to use and accept the other answer but will also try yours at some point.